# Python error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that goes through all the items of a list, here:

```
def lunch():
global tl
print("You have %s minutes until school starts." % (tl))
go=True
lunch=["pasta","pb+j","chicken","cheez its","goldfish","pirate's booty","cookie","cupcake","gogurt","strawberries","apple","grapes","carrots","bell peppers","pea pods"]
a=0
while a<len(lunch)-4:
    print("Do you pack or buy your lunch? (p,b)")
    lunch=input()
    if lunch=="pack" or lunch=="p":
        go2=True
        while go2:
            print("Do you want %s, %s, or %s?" % (lunch[a],lunch[a+1],lunch[a+2]))
            l=input()
            if not(l==lunch[a] or l==lunch[a+1] or l==lunch[a+2]):
                print("What?")
            else:
                print("Yay!")
                go2=False
        a+=3
```

but I keep getting the error ""IndexError: string index out of range" for the line

```
print("Do you want %s, %s, or %s?" % (lunch[a],lunch[a+1],lunch[a+2]))
```

I know that this means the index is more than or less than what it can index (more than or less than the length of the list minus one), but it shouldn't be doing that because it starts at zero and ends four before the list ends.

Comment: Umm, but you have `a+=3`. Why? Might that be the source of the `IndexError`?

Comment: the problem is that you overwrite `lunch` list with `lunch=input()`

Comment: @Aiven Probably more likely than my `a+=3` observation. Good spot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I overwrote the variable `lunch`, like Aiven said. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

your issue is that the reference to the index in `lunch[a+n]` is extending out of bounds. You could represent your choices like so.

```
lunch = ['pasta', 'pudding', 'cereal', 'steak']

print('Would you like {0} or {1} or {2} or {3}'.format(*lunch))
```